# To extract remote files, use tika.open(url) or wget to download to local first?

Tags: solr, wget, apache-tika

Tika can use a url parameter to extract remote files. and we can also download the remote file, then let tika extract it like a local file. From the performance and correctness views, which way is a better choice? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would be faster to just extract it from the URL, thus avoiding excessive read/write on you local system. Thats what I do when parsing files with tika. Fast and straight forward.